# Does vacuous truth mean non-bivalent truth?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Let $A=\emptyset$ be the empty set.

Let $B\equiv(\forall x\in A.P(x)\land \neg P(x))$

$B$ is vacuously true.

So, I conclude that vacuously true is non-Boolean because for each $x\in A$, $P(x)$ can be true and false.

Is this correct?

There are mathematical proofs based on vacuously true statement. This is why it can be relevant.

Comment: What do you mean by "vacuously true is non-Boolean"?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey, I mean that P and not P are both true.

Comment: @Brian sorry, I corrected that.

Comment: For any $x\in A$, $P(x)$ and $\lnot P(x)$ are true in $B.$ But there are no $x\in A$... See how this works?

Comment: @Brian $B$ is vacuously true because $A$ is the empty set.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yes, I see how it works. It seems non-Boolean to me.

Comment: @MatheusLobo No, you don't see how it works. (Also, you are making up terms like "non-Boolean".) For all $x\in A,$ I am the king of Mars. Can there possibly be any relevance to anything that comes after "$\forall x\in A $" where $A$ is the empty set?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen yes, I do!

Comment: (Also I realize now I subconsciously went along with you saying "true in $B$", but that makes no sense. But that doesn't really matter much.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen There are mathematical proofs based on vacuously true statement. This is why it can be relevant.

Comment: @MatheusLobo Re: your first comment, you can't say "$P$ and $\neg P$", only "$P(x)$ and $\neg P(x)$". But, as you have noted, there is no such $x$! Therefore, these statements have no meaning since $x$ cannot be defined at the time that your write them. This does not, however, gives rise to the notion of a statement being neither true nor false (i.e. being independent of the axioms at play).

Comment: These issues of $P$ vs $P(x)$ really are irrelevant (although they do suggest some misconception on OP's part). If $S$ is any closed sentence, $\forall x\in\emptyset (S \land\lnot S)$ is true. This doesn't mean $S$ is true and $\lnot S$ is true.

Comment: @Brian let's say $x$ are integers and $P(x)\equiv (x=0)$. In this way it is possible to define both $x$ and $P(x)$.

Comment: @MatheusLobo That is an entirely different statement than what you have presented in your question. I do not see how that example relates to vacuous truths.

Comment: Regarding you most recent edit, it would be helpful if you defined what you mean "non-Boolean" and "true in $B$". This is not terminology that I have heard before.

Comment: @Brian In my question I presented it generally. In my last post, I just gave a particular case. I'm not sure where would there be a mistake regarding my last post. If there is one, I would love to know.

Comment: @Brian I changed it to $\forall x\in A$. I also defined what I mean by non-Boolean.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit, yes, both $\forall x\in\emptyset P(x)$ and $\forall x\in \emptyset\lnot P(x)$ are true. But the latter does not imply that $\forall x\in \emptyset P(x)$ is false... it is not its negation. You are improperly exchanging a quantifier and a $\lnot$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen for each $x$ in $A$, if the truth table for $\neg P(x)$ is $1$ (true), then for $P(x)$ it is $0$ (false).

Comment: @MatheusLobo That is true... it also does not refute what I said. It is true that $\forall x\in A \lnot P(x)$ implies $\lnot \forall x\in A P(x)$ *if $A$ is nonempty*, if that is what you were getting at. The negation of $\forall x\in A P(x)$ *is* equivalent to $\exists x\in A \lnot P(x).$ So if $A$ is nonempty, you can argue "Let $x\in A$. Then by our premise $\forall x\in A\lnot P(x)$,we have $\lnot P(x).$ Hence we have $\exists x\in A \lnot P(x),$ which as I said before is equivalent to $\lnot\forall x\in A P(x).$" But from the very first clause, that argument depends on $A$ being nonempty.

Comment: "∀x∈A.P(x) can be true and false" WRONG: "∀x∈A.P(x)" and "∀x∈A.¬P(x)" are not one the negation of the other. Consider an example **not** regarding vacuous truth: "∀x∈N Even(x)" and "∀x∈N Odd(x) [i.e. not-Even(x)]" are **both** false.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! I corrected that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$B$ has what you mean by a Boolean (bivalent) truth value precisely because it is only *vacuously* true: It is true because there are no $x \in A$. And since there are no $x \in A$, *there are no $x$ such that both $P(x)$ and $\neg P(x)$ is true*.

Claiming something like "both () and ¬() are true" doesn't actually entirely make sense, because it is missing information, and I believe that's where the source of the confusion lies. **A statement with an open variable, such as $P(x) \land \neg P(x)$, is not just true or false, it is only true or false under a particular variable assignment which maps an object from the domain to the variable $x$.** We can not talk about the truth value of $P(x) \land \neg P(x)$ without talking about an object that $x$ refers to.

So whenever we say that $P(x) \land \neg P(x)$ is true, this means that we have at hand a concrete object from $A$ assigned to the variable $x$ of which $P(x) \land \neg P(x)$ is true. But there can be no such object, since $A$ is empty!

Analagously, claiming that $P(x) \land \neg P(x)$ is false would mean we are talking about a concrete object from $A$ mapped to the variable $x$ of which the statement is false. But again: Such an object can not exist, because $A$ is empty. And since there is no object in $A$ of which $P(x) \land \neg P(x)$  is is false, there is no counter witness to the universal quantifier. (**Remember that the only way for a universal statement $\forall x \in A. S$ to become false is if there is a counter witness, at least one object from the domain of $A$ of which $S$ is false. If there is no counter witness, the universal statement is true.**) And since there is no counter witness, $B = \forall x \in A. P(x) \land \neg P(x)$ is true. This is precisely what is called *vacuous truth*: $\forall x \in A. \ldots$ is true because there are no objects in $A$ at all.

But $B$ is *not* simultaneously false. Because that would mean we have a counter witness $x \in A$ of which $P(x) \land \neg P(x)$ is false. But as shown above -- since there are no objects to begin with, such a counter witness can not exist, and therefore $B = \forall x \in A. ...$ can not be false.

In sum, there is no interpretation, no variable assignment that makes either $B$ or the embedded statement $P(x) \land \neg P(x)$ both true and false at the same time, so the truth values are the classical Boolean truth values without gluts or gaps.

---

You changed your question after I had already written my full answer...

Indeed, (1) $\forall x. P(x)$ and (2) $\forall x. \neg P(x)$ are both true. They are vacuously true since $A$ is empty. But this doesn't mean that anything is true and false at the same time. **The two sentences are not negations of each other: The negation is embedded deeper in the formulas**. From (1) being true we may *not* infer that (2) is false or vice versa, because (2) does not have the shape $\neg (1)$ and (1) does not have the shape $\neg (2)$. Only if the negation is on the outside, the statements immediately have opposing truth values, but this is not the case here. We need to look deeper inside the quantified statements.

Again: Truth of open formulas is relative to variable assignments. From $\forall x \in A. P(x)$ we can conclude that $P(x)$ is true under every assignment of an object from $A$ to a varible $x$. From $\forall x \in A. P(x)$ we can conclude that $\neg P(x)$ is true and hence $P(x)$ false under every assignment of an object from $A$ to a varible $x$.

But there will be no variable assignment such that both $P(x)$ and $\neg P(x)$ are true. Why? Because there are no variable assignments to begin with -- $A$ is empty, so we never get to actually evaluating $P(x)$ and $\neg P(x)$ for any concrete value of $x$.

Again: There is no interpretation, no variable assignment under which $P(x)$ is simultaneously true and false, precisely because there are no objects in $A$ to assign to $x$ in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I edited it regarding the bounded variable.

Comment: @MatheusLobo I adapted my answer accordingly.